# Rails Spree Commerse - Cart content overriden when login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am using Spree Commerce(Ruby on Rails Framework) and I have a requirement where I need to keep the items in cart when the user login after selection of products. Help!!!

Thanks.

Comment: please let me know the reason before down vote. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Specify the Spree version please. Are you using the allow_guest_checkout option(can be set on the admin preferences) ?

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral Thanks for showing interest. I am using 'spree 3.0.4' and allow_guest_checkout option is set to false.

Comment: Try to set to true, since the order(cart) is saved on database it will be replaced on login, maybe with guest checkout it will replace the cart by the guest current order.

Comment: @CassioS.Cabral Couldn't work for me. Finally end up with changing reference of cart item's Order to logged in user's Order. Thanks for you interest.